# password_verify and special characters in password

Tags: php, passwords

I know this has to be a common question, but I can't find the answer.

I'm using PHP's password_verify.  If the password contains "&" it won't verify.  Without the "&" it does.  What do I need to do to escape the character?

```
<?php

$password_entered = "Password&";
$stored_secret = '$2y$12$oG8A4pbZSfQFxBQ0cHcJTuJ1h7wzzhlMnqjhnurN4.0/AfS/Wp9W2';
if (password_verify($newstr, $stored_secret))
{
echo "Right\n";
}
else
{
echo "Wrong\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Where is `$newstr` set?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly ignoring that `$newstr` is not set and you meant `$password_entered` instead.

It looks like your running htmlentities/htmlspecialchars on the user input, (which you are not showing), so it's breaking it.

The following matches your hash: `Password&amp;`.

```
<?php
$password_entered = "Password&amp;";
$stored_secret = '$2y$12$oG8A4pbZSfQFxBQ0cHcJTuJ1h7wzzhlMnqjhnurN4.0/AfS/Wp9W2';
if (password_verify($password_entered, $stored_secret)) {
    echo "Right\n";
} else {
    echo "Wrong\n";
}
?>
```

https://3v4l.org/SjfRG

Comment: Yes, I was having similar issues and when I applied htmlentities($password) it worked for me.